# Multidimensional NIntegrate with codimension 1 singularity

Tags: numerical-integration

I have the following integral

```
NIntegrate[(Sin[u1w1]*Sin[u2w1]*Sin[u3w1]*((-Cos[u2w2])*Cos[u3w1]*Sin[u1w1]*Sin[u1w2]*Sin[u2w1] + 
     Cos[u1w2]*Cos[u3w1]*Sin[u1w1]*Sin[u2w1]*Sin[u2w2] + Cos[u2w1]*Cos[u3w2]*Sin[u1w1]*Sin[u1w2]*Sin[u3w1] - 
     Cos[u1w1]*Cos[u3w2]*Sin[u2w1]*Sin[u2w2]*Sin[u3w1] - Cos[u1w2]*Cos[u2w1]*Sin[u1w1]*Sin[u3w1]*Sin[u3w2] + 
     Cos[u1w1]*Cos[u2w2]*Sin[u2w1]*Sin[u3w1]*Sin[u3w2])*Sin[u4w1]*Sin[u5w1]*((-Cos[u4w2])*Cos[u5w1]*Sin[u3w1]*Sin[u3w2]*Sin[u4w1] + 
     Cos[u3w2]*Cos[u5w1]*Sin[u3w1]*Sin[u4w1]*Sin[u4w2] + Cos[u4w1]*Cos[u5w2]*Sin[u3w1]*Sin[u3w2]*Sin[u5w1] - 
     Cos[u3w1]*Cos[u5w2]*Sin[u4w1]*Sin[u4w2]*Sin[u5w1] - Cos[u3w2]*Cos[u4w1]*Sin[u3w1]*Sin[u5w1]*Sin[u5w2] + 
     Cos[u3w1]*Cos[u4w2]*Sin[u4w1]*Sin[u5w1]*Sin[u5w2])*Sin[u6w1]*(Cos[u4w2]*Cos[u6w1]*Sin[u1w1]*Sin[u1w2]*Sin[u4w1] - 
     Cos[u1w2]*Cos[u6w1]*Sin[u1w1]*Sin[u4w1]*Sin[u4w2] - Cos[u4w1]*Cos[u6w2]*Sin[u1w1]*Sin[u1w2]*Sin[u6w1] + 
     Cos[u1w1]*Cos[u6w2]*Sin[u4w1]*Sin[u4w2]*Sin[u6w1] + Cos[u1w2]*Cos[u4w1]*Sin[u1w1]*Sin[u6w1]*Sin[u6w2] - 
     Cos[u1w1]*Cos[u4w2]*Sin[u4w1]*Sin[u6w1]*Sin[u6w2])*(Cos[u5w2]*Cos[u6w1]*Sin[u2w1]*Sin[u2w2]*Sin[u5w1] - 
     Cos[u2w2]*Cos[u6w1]*Sin[u2w1]*Sin[u5w1]*Sin[u5w2] - Cos[u5w1]*Cos[u6w2]*Sin[u2w1]*Sin[u2w2]*Sin[u6w1] + 
     Cos[u2w1]*Cos[u6w2]*Sin[u5w1]*Sin[u5w2]*Sin[u6w1] + Cos[u2w2]*Cos[u5w1]*Sin[u2w1]*Sin[u6w1]*Sin[u6w2] - 
     Cos[u2w1]*Cos[u5w2]*Sin[u5w1]*Sin[u6w1]*Sin[u6w2]))/((1 - Cos[u1w1]*Cos[u2w1] - Cos[u1w2]*Cos[u2w2]*Sin[u1w1]*Sin[u2w1] - 
     Sin[u1w1]*Sin[u1w2]*Sin[u2w1]*Sin[u2w2])*(1 - Cos[u1w1]*Cos[u3w1] - Cos[u1w2]*Cos[u3w2]*Sin[u1w1]*Sin[u3w1] - 
     Sin[u1w1]*Sin[u1w2]*Sin[u3w1]*Sin[u3w2])*(1 - Cos[u3w1]*Cos[u4w1] - Cos[u3w2]*Cos[u4w2]*Sin[u3w1]*Sin[u4w1] - 
     Sin[u3w1]*Sin[u3w2]*Sin[u4w1]*Sin[u4w2])*(1 - Cos[u2w1]*Cos[u5w1] - Cos[u2w2]*Cos[u5w2]*Sin[u2w1]*Sin[u5w1] - 
     Sin[u2w1]*Sin[u2w2]*Sin[u5w1]*Sin[u5w2])*(1 - Cos[u3w1]*Cos[u5w1] - Cos[u3w2]*Cos[u5w2]*Sin[u3w1]*Sin[u5w1] - 
     Sin[u3w1]*Sin[u3w2]*Sin[u5w1]*Sin[u5w2])*(1 - Cos[u1w1]*Cos[u6w1] - Cos[u1w2]*Cos[u6w2]*Sin[u1w1]*Sin[u6w1] - 
     Sin[u1w1]*Sin[u1w2]*Sin[u6w1]*Sin[u6w2])*(1 - Cos[u4w1]*Cos[u6w1] - Cos[u4w2]*Cos[u6w2]*Sin[u4w1]*Sin[u6w1] - 
     Sin[u4w1]*Sin[u4w2]*Sin[u6w1]*Sin[u6w2])*(1 - Cos[u5w1]*Cos[u6w1] - Cos[u5w2]*Cos[u6w2]*Sin[u5w1]*Sin[u6w1] - 
     Sin[u5w1]*Sin[u5w2]*Sin[u6w1]*Sin[u6w2])), {u1w1, 0, Pi}, {u1w2, 0, 2*Pi}, {u2w1, 0, Pi}, {u2w2, 0, 2*Pi}, {u3w1, 0, Pi}, 
  {u3w2, 0, 2*Pi}, {u4w1, 0, Pi}, {u4w2, 0, 2*Pi}, {u5w1, 0, Pi}, {u5w2, 0, 2*Pi}, {u6w1, 0, Pi}, {u6w2, 0, 2*Pi}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 100, AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> Infinity]
```

There is a singularity when $uiwk=ujwk$ for all $k$ and all pairs $i\neq j$ (notice the denominator). I think the singularity is integrable; however, I do not know how to specify it to NIntegrate. Every time I try, with different integration methods and precision setting, I get NIntegrate::slwcon or other errors. Thanks for any help!

Comment: mother of god...

Comment: :-D It comes from integrating a rational function over $(\mathbb{S}^2)^{\times 6}$ after transforming in spherical coordinates. I also tried NIntegrate with {x,y,z}\in Sphere[] in Cartesian coordinates but somehow the integration does not work on more than two spheres...

Comment: I don't think multidimensional integration can be done precisely at all.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I do not do numerics so this information is also helpful. You mean that NIntegrate can not control error of multidimensional integrals?

Comment: For regular methods complexity grows exponentially with dimensions, and if you use Monte Carlo then precision is low $\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$. That's even without accounting for singularities.

Comment: Actually, it would be enough for me to know if the integral is 0 or not. I have two function $f_1$, $f_2$ which look as above. Let $f_1$ denote the above function. If I take $f=f_1 + f_2$, then its integral $I(f)$ should be $0$ from a general theory. Miraculously, Mathematica confirmed I(f) ~ 0 over night although $f\neq 0$ and Simplify[f] runs forever. I would like to know if already $I(f_i)=0$ of $I(f_1)=-I(f_2)$.